# What is the easiest way to integrate static pages into Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a landing page that was passed to me by a designer, the Structure is like this

```
|_startup
    |_common-files
        |_css
        |_fonts
        |_icons
        |_img
        |_js
        |_less
    |_flat-ui
        |_bootstrap
            |_css
            |_fonts
            |_js
        |_fonts
        |_icons
        |_img
        |_js
        |_less
    |_ui-kit
|_static
    |_css
    |_less
index.html
```

I didn't type the whole structure, but the idea is, it's quite a bit of directory, and it might be tough to separate it into javascript, css, image assets, and fonts(I am not sure where fonts go).  My thoughts are,  should I just have a subdomain and put this about page? I do want to integrate the page into my rails project.  My question is, is there an easy way to integrate an independent page into my rails project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the book **[Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html)**:

> A Rails application can deliver static web pages just like an ordinary
>   web server. The pages are delivered fast and no Ruby code is required.
>   The Rails application server looks for any pages in the public folder
>   by default.

So you can drop the directory into your application *public/* folder.

Comment: Thanks, I goof up, I put all static pages into /intro, and I request /intro, however, I should have request /intro/ since all assets are relative.